# Universal Linking iOS 9 - URL with a hashtag?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, universal

I can't appear to get universal linking working when the url has a hashtag in it?  What do I do?  I've even tried converting it over to %23..  URLS w/o a hashtag in it when I set it up work fine.

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "MY_APP",
        "paths":["/%23MY_ROUTE"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You could try matching on `"/?MY_ROUTE"` which will accept any character in place of the `?`

Comment: I have replaced it to be "paths": ["/?MY_ROUTE"].....


This doesn't appear to work when I navigate to https://example.com/#MY_ROUTE

Comment: The `#` symbol is used for anchors in URLs, so it usually doesn't match in situations like this. What is the full URL you are trying to use?

Comment: Universal links drops everything after #, so there is no way to match URL after the hashtag. One solution would be to match everything, filter out the supported path in the app and everything else open in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Adding a solution for anyone who comes by looking for one. Now it's possible to support deep linking of URL with hashtag(#) also, the solution for this case would be to use a pattern matching any other part of URL. Following example uses the path to match the URL when there is a mix of components,

For an URL like `www.samplehost.com/#/p/something?id=12345`

```
"/": "*/something*"
```

If it's a simple URL that just has a fragment or path alone, direct pattern matching will suffice. Apple's documentation shows some simple URL patterns

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode/supporting-associated-domains

**NOTE:**
Association file changes are mapped to the app during installation only. There is some time duration when this file update will happen on successive re-installs after updating of file.

For example, the first time you update the association file at the domain and re-install the app to check new changes, it will work. If you make repeated changes on the JSON file and re-install the app in that same time frame, you might get a cached copy. When you find that a working pattern is newly added to the JSON file and the app doesn't pick it, you know a cached copy is used by the app. In such cases re-install the app later to verify the new update.